# BigQuery Script: Loop over records of a table

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery script, I'm trying to loop over records of a table and perform some operation for each record. I could not find direct approach where I can have something like below in script:

```
DECLARE record STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>;

LOOP (SELECT id, name FROM Testing.Employee)
  SET record = (id, name)
  -- Do something with record
END LOOP;
```

I tried is to use ARRAY of STRUCT like below:

```
DECLARE all_rows ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>>;
SET all_rows = ( select as STRUCT id, name from Testing.Employees );
```

But it rightly gives type coerce error, as I'm trying to assign STRUCT to ARRAY type. Let me know if there is alternative for iterating over dataset.

Comment: I suppose it depends on why you are looping.  Are you trying to do something that can't be handled by regular SQL?  `Do something with the record` is pretty vague, but most things can be handled with simple database first principles. Databases excel at doing things in sets, iterating over data one row at a time will often be much slower.  If you do need to iterate, it might be faster to do it outside of a database (python, R, etc).  It really depends on what you are trying to do.  Consider adding more detail to your post.

Comment: @rtenha I have posted a question with sample logic that I want to implement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927515/converting-loop-with-variables-to-bigquery-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting loop with variables to BigQuery SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927515/converting-loop-with-variables-to-bigquery-sql)

Comment: @SergiMuñoz No, it solves the problem statement but with some performance issues. Since that approach didn't seem to work for me, I started thinking to use script to solve the problem but got into another issue which is explained here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
DECLARE all_rows ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>>;
SET all_rows = ( SELECT ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT id, name from Testing.Employees) );
```